# Is it appropriate to post other people's comments as an answer if they solved the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I recently came across  [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285497/scheme-infinite-recursion) in which the poster solved their problem in the comments, along with other commenters, but the solution was not posted as an answer.  Given that other people might have a similar issue, I think it would be appropriate for the information that solved the problem to be an answer so that it is more easily accessible.  Is this the right thing to do, or would it be considered wrong here to post someone else's solution because it wasn't a formal answer?